# Creating register for mobile device using FOS not working

Tags: php, android, symfony

I am making a android application and I am working on implementing the database. Currently the Register (newAction). I do this through Symfony and let it return json objects to the application. We use Gazzle to test if it is correct. When I run the php file in cmd. it gives HTML code and from what I can see I have an undefined variable: persist However I have no clue where or if that is the sole reason for it not to work?

My RegisterAction:

```
public function newAction(Request $request){
  $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$body = $request->getContent();
$data = json_decode($body, true);

$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->createUser();

$user->setUsername($data['username']);
$username = $data['username'];
$user->setEmail($data['email']);
$user->setPlainPassword($data['plainPassword']);
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$em->$persist($user);



$errors = $validator->validate($user, null, ['Registration']);
if (count($errors) == 0) {
  $userManager->updateUser($user);
  $response = "User is created";

} else {
  $response = "Errors";
}
return new Response($user->getUsername());

}
```

My test.php

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
'base_url' => 'http://localhost:8000',
'defaults' => [
'exceptions' => false
]

]);

$data = array(

'email' => "test@test.nl",
'username' => "tim",
'plainPassword' => "12345"
);

 $response = $client->post('/api/createUser',[
 'body' => json_encode($data)
 ]);


  echo $response;
```

The gazzle output:

```
X-Debug-Token: 8175e9
X-Debug-Token-Link: /_profiler/8175e9
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <title>    Notice: Undefined variable: persist (500 Internal Server Error)
</title>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I don't really know what is wrong. and the error log doesn't really help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$em->$persist($user);
```

with this:

```
$em->persist($user);
```

Comment: Ty can't believed I was overlooking that

Comment: @KevinTheGreat It happens sometimes, we just miss the small things.